# Controlar cartão ponto de funcionários

Tags: php, array, table

Preciso fazer uma tabela em que mostre se o funcionário faltou ou não. se caso não possua falta mostrar suas batidas de ponto na frente da data respectiva.

Alguém pode me ajudar??

Exemplo:
No meu banco tenho vários funcionário cadastrados, supondo que tenho um funcionário com as seguintes batidas:

batida_id =>1 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 07:30  tipo  => entrada
batida_id =>2 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 12:00 tipo => saida
batida_id =>3 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 13:30 tipo => entrada
batida_id =>4 colaborador_id=> 1 data => 01/06/2016 batida => 17:00 tipo => saida

a partir dessas batidas preciso organizá-las colocando na frente da data respectiva:

ficaria algo assim:

01 - quarta-feira - 07:30 12:00 13:30 17:00
02 - quinta-feira -  falta
03 - sexta-feira  -  falta
04 - sábado  -  falta
(...)

Obs: como ele só tem batidas do dia **01/06/2016** preciso preencher o restante dos dias como **falta**:

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
  <th>Data</th>
  <th>Dia Semana</th>
  <th>Ocorrências</th>
  </tr>  <br />
        
    <?php
            
              
    $diasSemana[1] = 'Segunda-feira';
    $diasSemana[2] = 'Terça-feira';
    $diasSemana[3] = 'Quarta-feira';
    $diasSemana[4] = 'Quinta-feira';
    $diasSemana[5] = 'Sexta-feira';
    $diasSemana[6] = 'Sábado';
    $diasSemana[7] = 'Domingo';

   
    for($dias = 1; $dias <= date('t',strtotime('2016-06')); $dias++)
    
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>".$dias."</th>" . "<th>".$diasSemana[date('N', strtotime("2016-06-$dias"))] ."</th>" . "<th>";
   
      
        }
        
     
   echo "</tr>";
      
?>    
             </table>
```

Comment: Como está a receber os dados se falta ou não? cada tabela diz respeito a uma pessoa certo?

Comment: Se faltar como fica o campo data na tabela? `Null` ou `''` (vazio)?

Comment: no meu banco tenho a tabela "marcacoes" com as colunas: marcacao_id(int), colaborador_id(int),tipo(char)-> Obs* o tipo seria se é marcação de entrada ou saída representado por E ou S),data(date),registro(time)(são as batidas). Se na hora de preencher as datas com o array  e aquela data não tiver batida ele deve imprimir "falta".

Answer (score 0):

Creio que é isto que quer, o array `$batidas` vai armazenar esta informção por dia:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Dia Semana</th>
        <th>Ocorrências</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $diasSemana[1] = 'Segunda-feira';
    $diasSemana[2] = 'Terça-feira';
    $diasSemana[3] = 'Quarta-feira';
    $diasSemana[4] = 'Quinta-feira';
    $diasSemana[5] = 'Sexta-feira';
    $diasSemana[6] = 'Sábado';
    $diasSemana[7] = 'Domingo';

    $horas = ['falta', '7:30 12:00 13:30 17:00'];
    $batidas = array();
    for($dias = 1; $dias <= date('t',strtotime('2016-06')); $dias++) {
        $falta = $horas[rand(0, 1)];
        $batidas[] = array(
            'dia_mes' => $dias,
            'dia_semana' => $diasSemana[date('N', strtotime("2016-06-$dias"))],
            'falta' => $falta
        );
        echo '<tr>
                <th> '.$dias. '</th>
                <th>' .$diasSemana[date('N', strtotime("2016-06-$dias"))]. '</th>
                <th>' .$falta. '</th>
            </tr>';
    }
    ?>    
</table>
<?php echo '<pre>', print_r($batidas), '</pre>'; ?>
```

O parâmetro falta ou não, fiz ao acaso, pois não sei em que se está a apoiar para isso